# Using Bootstrap 4.5.2 with Webpack

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, frontend

I'm unable to apply the regular Bootstrap styles to my HTML elements. For example `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>` becomes just a default gray button. (I am able to override styles in custom.scss, so I can override the scss variables for bg-color, etc.)

[image]

Another issue is that Visual Studio's autocomplete doesn't know about some of Bootstrap's classes such as "form-group", but it does know about offset-xl-2 and some others.

Prior to building I run the `npm run mytest` script to use webpack, see package.json below.

index.js:

```
import "../css/custom.scss";
import 'bootstrap';
```

custom.scss:

```
// Required
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// Optional
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/code";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
```

package.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "exports-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.11.2",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.26.11",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.19.2",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "^3.2.11",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "bootstrap-js": "webpack --mode production --progress --profile --config webpack.bootstrap.js",
    "bootstrap-css": "node-sass --output-style compressed client/css/bootstrap.scss wwwroot/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "bundles": "npm run bootstrap-js && npm run bootstrap-css",
    "mytest": "webpack --mode development"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const config = {
    entry: './client/js/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/js/'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '../css/mainly.css'
    })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                    },
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

I insert the js and css into html inside _Layout.cshtml:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/mainly.css" />
    <script src="~/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: @import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot"; your sass file are on the same level as node_modules ? or you import it to app component ?

Comment: I can see you bundle the SASS in index.js, but not sure where you're inserting the CSS in to the HTML. Usually HtmlWebpackPlugin is used to insert it.  See https://github.com/JustAGuyCoding/spotlight-webpack for a working bootstrap example.

Comment: @Anthony I've updated with an example, I'm inserting css and js manually in _Layout.cshtml.

Comment: @robert Not sure, I'm trying to compile the scss that is in the bootstrap npm module and would like to override in client/js/index.js.

Comment: Don't you need a @import "~bootstrap/scss/buttons"; (or whatever your path is) to import the bootstrap styles for buttons?! In your custom.scss

Comment: there is _button.scss imported to main bootstrap.scss

Comment: Inside index.js, I think import 'bootstrap' bundles the JavaScript and the custom.scss will convert and bundle the Sass styling, I can't see an import in there...?

Comment: @Anthony, thanks for your input, I followed the documentation a little closer on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/#importing-precompiled-sass and wrote in my custom.scss `@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` then in another file main.scss: `@import "../css/custom.scss";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` After running webpack, now styles work and VS knows about the classes such as form.group! I'm wondering why webpack works despite my config being different from the link. E.g I'm not using autoprefixer or precss as you can see in my webpack.config.js.

Comment: @robert I think I resolved the initial problem, thanks!

Comment: Webpack will bundle whatever you import in index.js, without the autoprefixer and precss plugins in the config it won't know to apply those transformations, so the CSS produced will still work most of the time but won't have browser specific prefixes for edge cases auto-prefixed. I'm not sure why they're using PreCSS with SASS (see https://github.com/jonathantneal/precss) as it would seem redundant, but again those transformations won't be applied. You should probably update the config to match the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Add `style-loader` in webpack, for inject to page:

```
{
  loader: 'style-loader',
}
```

see [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/)